# Overlapping a transparent color with an icon on an image when a mouse is hovering on it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Good day,

I'm a beginner of Dart & Flutter, and have a challenge.

That is overlapping a transparent color with an icon on an image when a mouse is hovering on it.

You can see what I want to make here:

[image]

Below are source codes I'm trying,

```dart
InkResponse(
  highlightShape: BoxShape.rectangle,
  containedInkWell: true,
  onHover: (isHovering) {
    if (isHovering) {
    // maybe input something here
    } else {
    // maybe input something here
    }
  },
  onTap: () => {showMyDialog()},
  child: Ink.image(
    width: 350.0,
    height: 280.0,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    image: Image.asset('images/technology.png').image,
  ),
)
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve it.

Could you give me a hint or a solution?

It will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a variable like this:

```
bool isHovered = false;
```

then in your build method change your `InkResponse` widget to this:

```
InkWell( 
        onHover: (isHovering) {
          setState(() {
            isHovered = isHovering;
          });
        },
        onTap: () => {},
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image(
              width: 350.0,
              height: 280.0,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: Image.asset('images/technology.png').image,
            ),
            isHovered
                ? Container(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 280.0,
                    color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.4),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 34,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
                : SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
      )
```